# Groovy sends the empty value into the JMeter Request

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

From the Previous request Groovy Script properly saving the data into the csv file, but passing the empty value in the following request.

Not sure exactly what went wrong. Tried hardcoded the Value and the request is fine.

```
https://xx.xx.xx.xxx/xx/projects/2228/week-endings/${__groovy(new%20File('${DH-week-endings}').readLines().get(${counter_value}),)}/departments/${id}/timecards
```

And here is error from the log

```
2022-01-11 12:56:55,519 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2022-01-11 12:56:55,549 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script66$_run_closure1) values: [Script66$_run_closure1@61d664cd]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), get(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy.execute(Groovy.java:120) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:91) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.unwrapProperty(TestBeanHelper.java:129) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.TestBeanHelper.prepare(TestBeanHelper.java:84) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:202) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:382) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_311]
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script66$_run_closure1) values: [Script66$_run_closure1@61d664cd]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), get(java.lang.String), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    ... 10 more
```

Please see the below screenshots
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe correct syntax would be something like:

```
${__groovy(new File(vars.get('DH-week-endings')).readLines().get(vars.get('counter_value') as int),)}
```

1. If you're uncertain regarding building a proper JMeter Function - go for the [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating all remaining Beanshell elements
3. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy/Beanshell scripts, go for [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) instead